# How to I connect to ASPNETDB.MDF via webconfig?

Tags: asp.net, form-authentication

I have a database in my App_Data that was created automatically by the system when I incorporated **Membership** and **Role Manager** and **Profile** into my web application.

The problem is there is no connectionstring for ASPNETDB, it wasn't created by the system.  I assume it stored elsewhere, I've a feeling machine.config.

I have detacted this database from app_data and reconnected and store it in my SQL SERVER 2008.

How to I connect to it via Webconfig.sys to get my Application services working?

Regards,
Tea

Answer (score 0):

I copied what was in machine.config under `<provider>`, `<roleManager>` and `<Profile>`.  Added a connection string.  Worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
<system.web>
<membership defaultProvider="Pragatee_MLM_MamberProvider"> <providers> <add connectionStringName="ConnectionPragatee" enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
 enablePasswordReset="true" applicationName="PragateeMLM" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" name="Pragatee_MLM_MamberProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" /></providers></membership><roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" defaultProvider="Pragatee_MLM_RoleProvider"><providers><add applicationName="PragateeMLM" connectionStringName="ConnectionPragatee" name="Pragatee_MLM_RoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"/></providers></roleManager></system.web>
```